# CSS: Stretch DIV to Fullscreen while parent DIV is bigger than 100%

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on a website which will use a scroll effect to navigate between pages.
Therefore, all pages are contained in one huge parent DIV (width:20000em;), the resultant overflow is hidden.

My issue: I'd love to expand each single page to FULLSCREEN. The height is no problem, but I couldn't find any possibility to stretch the width of a page's DIV container to the screen width, because it will always fill in 100% of it's parent element which is the 200000em overall DIV.

Any ideas, best practices, workarounds?
Should I get the screen width (browser dimensions) by Javascript? I'm using jQuery anyway...

The jQuery-Plugin I'm using is "scrollable" (http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html)

See a current work-in-progress version of the site here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16183441/area51/scroll.html

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I haven't used it, but this tutorial seems to give you some tricks for doing that: http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/detect-screen-size-css-style/